# Sql how to group column without losing data

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, row

I'm using SQL Server 2014 and I want to group my row without losing data.

Here's what I have so far:

[image]

What I want to achieve is this :

[image]

Comment: How do you know rows 2 & 3 relate to row 1 and not row 4?  Normally you would just min/max the columns that you need to pull together and group by the other columns.  However dateFacture isn't enough and it appears codeTaxe1 needs to be part of the group by; but lacks data in columns for rows 2 & 3... so simply put you can't given the information provided; as we have no way of telling if rows 2&3 belong to rows 1 or 4.  Order in a database isn't guaranteed so that will not work.

Comment: To group rows, you first need to define a uniqueness/grouping criteria/columns. It's not clear to me which one is it. Please list the columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is tricky.  Basically the idea is an unpivot and re-pivot, but with a twist:

```
select t.id,
       max(case when which = 'codeTaxe1' then val end) as codeTaxe1,
       max(case when which = 'codeTaxe2' then val end) as codeTaxe2,
       . . . 
from t cross apply
     (select v.*, row_number() over (order by (select null)) as seqnum
      from (values (t.codeTaxe1, 'codeTaxe1'), (t.codeTaxe2, 'codeTaxe2'), . . .
           ) v(val, which)
      where val is not null
     ) tt
group by t.id, seqnum;
```